# Adding items to list and array

Tags: c#, beginner, array

I am new to C# and am trying to understand if there is a very simple way to rewrite this code.

```
List<Vertex<string>> vertices = new List<Vertex<string>>
                (
                    new Vertex<string>[]
                        {
                    new Vertex<string>("Los Angeles"),
                    new Vertex<string>("San Francisco"),
                    new Vertex<string>("Las Vegas"),
                    new Vertex<string>("Seattle"),
                    new Vertex<string>("Austin"),
                    new Vertex<string>("Portland")
                        }
                );

                // Establish edges; Ex. Los Angeles -> San Francisco, Las Vegas, Portland
                vertices[0].AddEdges(new List<Vertex<string>>(new Vertex<string>[]
                {
                vertices[1], vertices[2], vertices[5]
                }));
```

some thing like the below to make it easy to understand

```
List<Vertex<string>> vertices = new List<Vertex<string>>();
            var vrtx = new Vertex<string>[]
                {
                new Vertex<string>("Los Angeles"),
                new Vertex<string>("San Francisco"),
                new Vertex<string>("Las Vegas"),
                new Vertex<string>("Seattle"),
                new Vertex<string>("Austin"),
                new Vertex<string>("Portland")
            };
```

Comment: For one work on indent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for initialization of `List` you can use this approach:

```
var vertices = new[]
    {
        "Los Angeles",
        "San Francisco",
        "Las Vegas",
        "Seattle",
        "Austin"
        "Portland"
    }
    .Select(city => new Vertex<string>(city))
    .ToList();
```

`vertices` will be of the `List<Vertex<string>>` type and you don't need to repeat `new Vertex<string>(...)` multiple times. Read about LINQ since it is one of the greatest features of C#.

---

I suggest to change the signature of the `AddEdges` method to

```
AddEdges(params Vertex<string>[] vertices)
```

Now you can call `AddEdges` in this way:

```
vertices[0].AddEdges(vertices[1], vertices[2], vertices[5]);
```

Read about `params` keyword.

Or you can define the method like:

```
AddEdges(IEnumerable<Vertex<string>> vertices)
```

and call it like this:

```
vertices[0].AddEdges(new[] { vertices[1], vertices[2], vertices[5] });
```

---

In my opinion it's not a good style to describe relations between objects via populating some collections using magic indices. I need to look at `vertices` list to know what is the `vertices[2]`. The biggest problem with your approach is if I change order of vertices inside `vertices` list, the cities network will be broken.

As an option you can declare enum with your cities:

```
public enum City
{
    LosAngeles,
    SanFrancisco,
    LasVegas,
    Seattle,
    Austin,
    Portland
}
```

To describe relations between them use `Dictionary`:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<City, City[]> CitiesEdges =
    new Dictionary<City, City[]>
    {
        [City.LosAngeles] = new[]
        {
            City.SanFrancisco,
            City.LasVegas,
            City.Portland
        },
        // ... add other edges
    };
```

And finally we'll create map for cities names:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<City, string> CitiesNames =
    new Dictionary<City, string>
    {
        [City.LosAngeles] = "Los Angeles",
        // ... add other names
    };
```

Then building of the entire cities network will be:

```
var verticesMap = Enum.GetValues(typeof(City))
                      .Cast<City>()
                      .ToDictionary(c => c,
                                    c => new Vertex<string>(CitiesNames[c]));

foreach (var vertex in verticesMap)
{
    var edges = CitiesEdges[vertex.Key].Select(c => verticesMap[c]);
    vertex.Value.AddEdges(edges);
}

var vertices = verticesMap.Values.ToList();
```

The big advantage of this approach is you can forget about edges building code and operate only by dictionaries above. If you need to add new city in your network you just add one new constant to `City` enum, new entry to `CitiesEdges` dictionary and new entry to `CitiesNames` dictionary.

All relations between cities is super clear since you now manipulate by semantically named constants rather than magic indices. Also now you don't depend on order of vertices inside `vertices` list.